# subscript includes a letter and a number

Tags: subscripts

I have a letter with subscript:

```
\alpha_{3r}
```

But the subscript is not suitable:

[image]

I wish to have a style as:

[image]

in which the position of `1r` is lower than before case, moreover the size of `r` is not smaller than `1`.
I  think this format is so better the previous default case.
Is there any way to reach the goal?

Comment: You can lower the subscript by using `\alpha^{}_{1r}`, but I'd not make 1 smaller: in normal size it is higher than r.

Comment: note that the drop of the subscript depends on the font and is different in display math and inline math, you have only provided a fragment so hard to say exactly what to change

Comment: Why do you want `r` to be as tall as `1`?

Answer (score 2):

A neat trick would be to use the package `relsize`. Then you can try

```
$$\alpha_{1\mathlarger{r}}$$
```

Comment: Please use `\[ .. \]` instead of  `$$..$$`. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/125871

Answer (score 1):

I advise against doing either of these, but depending on whether you want the `1` to shrink to the size of the `r` or want the `r` to grow to the size of the `1`, you could use `scalerel` as in  the following code:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{scalerel}

\begin{document}

$\alpha_{1\scalerel*{r}{1}}\quad\alpha_{\scalerel*{1}{r}r}$

\end{document}
```